# Get this error message in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

[image: This is my SQL table]

My queries tab looks like this:

```
insert into dbo.booking 
values ('Member ID', 'Court ID', 'Date', 'Timeslot', 'Price') 

insert into dbo.booking 
values ('1', '1', '19/12/19', '07:00 - 17:00', 'Morning £12 + 2') 

select * from dbo.booking
```

But, I get this error when I execute it:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Member ID' to data type int

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it please?

Comment: You are using single quotes for columns names.  That is one major error, so I'm voting to close as a typographical error.

Comment: Also, for timeslot, you should have 2 columns, one for the start one for the end. You'll using the completely wrong data type to store times.

Comment: Why do you try to insert what appears to be column headers? Your schema also leaves a lot of room for improvement. `date` and `timeslot` should be dropped and replace by *two* `datetime` columns for the begin and the end of the timeslot. Either way, `timeslot` shouldn't be `varchar`. `price` also shouldn't be varchar but some numeric type.

Answer (score 2):

The INSERT is wrongly used.

Try it like this:

```
insert into dbo.booking ([Member ID], [Court ID], [Date], [Timeslot], Price) values 
(1, 1, '2019-12-19', '07:00 - 17:00', N'Morning £12 + 2')
```

You can see from the reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql) that the syntax is more like this example:

```
INSERT INTO database_name.schema_name.table_or_view_name 
( column1, column2 ) VALUES 
( 'text', 42 ), 
( 'other text', 69 )
```

integer values don't need the single-quotes.
And values for a NVARCHAR should be prefixed with a N.

The error that you had was because the first insert tried to insert text values into number fields.
And that only works if that text can be implicitly casted to a number.