# What is wrong here for me to get this error message in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

My table structure:

[image: My table]

My query:

```
insert into dbo.booking ([Member ID], [Court ID], [Date], [Timeslot], Price)  
values (1, 1, '2019-12-19', '07:00 - 17:00', N'Morning £12 + 2')

select * from dbo.booking
```

Then the error message:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here to get that error message?

Comment: The value `'07:00 - 17:00'` inserted into `[Timeslot]` do not match `datetime` datatype.

Comment: 2 accounts, or should you and the other Joe collaborate to do your homework together? https://stackoverflow.com/q/59695566/2029983 Either way, the advice I gave them/you before stands though. Use 2 columns, with the correct data type.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `timeslot`, because a single `datetime` column cannot contain a range of times.

One idea is a string -- because that is what you are inserting.  Another would be to have two columns, say `timeslot_from` and `timeslot_to`.

Then, when that is fixed, you can address `price`.

Comment: `Price` also has a `varchar` value being passed.